# Mailkit TextPart IsHtml Content type check does not work

Tags: html, email, mime-types, mailkit, mimekit

Dear Friends,

```
 TextPart textPart = new TextPart();
    textPart.Text = body; // body contains the html text.
    if(textPart.IsHtml)
    {
    }else { }
```

text part IsHtml is not giving me the correct result. I know my body text contains HTML but still, it goes in else condition.

Then I look into this conversation but when I wrote it. It gives error on ContentType.
char does not contain the information of contentType.

```
 var bodyii = textPart.Text.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType("text", "html"));
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textPart.IsHtml` doesn't examine the `textPart.Text` to see if it contains html tags, it examines the `textPart.ContentTyp`e to see if it matches `text/html`. When you create a `TextPart` using the default constructor, it creates `text/plain`, not `text/html`.

You need to use:

```
TextPart textPart = new TextPart ("html");
```

The following code of yours:

```
var bodyii = textPart.Text.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType("text", "html"));
```

gets an error because `textPart.Text` is a `string`, which means your LINQ expression operates on `char` elements and a `char` does not have a `ContentType` property.

In other words, if you do:

```
textPart.Text = "This is some text.";
```

Then your LINQ expression, translated to more simplistic C# code using a forewach loop would look like this:

```
char bodyii = 0;
foreach (char x in textPart.Text)
{
    if (x.ContentType.IsMimeType("text", "html"))
    {
        bodyii = x;
        break;
    }
}
```

Does that code make sense to you? It shouldn't which is why the compiler is giving you an error.